# SQL replicaton - collecting data

Tags: sql-server, database-replication

I have master SQL server with DB Central and a lot of satellite SQL servers with DB Client. I need to collect data from log tables(LogTable) on Client(each client has own ID in log table) to one big table on Central(LogTableCentral).

- Data must go only from Client to Central
- On each Client I want to have only data for this Client
- I need solution with minimal amount of work on client side because of count of clients
- Central is MS SQL server Enterprise, Clients are MS SQL server 2005, 2008

Thanks a lot

EDIT: data can be collected periodically(for example: every day at 01:00)

Comment: Is your requirement to replicate the data immediate (as it is recorded), or is it acceptable to have some sort of scheduled process to do this periodically?

Answer (score 0):

As it is done periodically, have you considered using SSIS for this task?

You can add multiple data connections, and then have a series of data sources (each connected to one of the connections) feeding into a data destination (also connected to one of the data sources)

You could then schedule this as part of a SQL Agent Job. Something like this:

[image]

Comment: Good advice thanks(I never used SSIS), but with replication I do not need to handle new inserts, updates, deletes....all this thinks handles replication. SSIS handles this for me too, if yes how can I setup it?

Comment: Not sure, I must admit, I was just envisaging a full-pull of the data, which i realise is probably not feasible for you. I've never used SSIS to handle I/U/D in this way. It may be worth looking at the merge task for this. Regardless, the agent job may be useful for scheduling any replication tasks, whatever form they take,